# Can't get move constructor to run

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, curly-braces, move-constructor, uniform-initialization

**C++11**

I'm having trouble using the move constructor. I have a simple container class, called `Number`, whose only data member is an integer. I have the following code:

```
//Number.h
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H
#include <iostream>

class Number
{
public:
    Number();
    Number(int ipar);
    Number(const Number& src);
    Number(Number&& src);
private:
    int num;
};

#endif
```

**and**

```
//Number.cpp
#include "Number.h"

Number::Number()
{
    std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl;
}

Number::Number(int ipar) : num(ipar)
{
    std::cout << "integer argument ctor" << std::endl;
}

Number::Number(const Number& src) : num(src.num)
{
    std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
}

Number::Number(Number&& src) : num(src.num)
{
    std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
}
```

**and**

```
//main.cpp
#include "Number.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Part A:" << endl;
    Number n1(1);
    cout << "Part B:" << endl;
    Number n2(n1);
    cout << "Part C:" << endl;
    Number n3{Number{n1}};
    cout << "Part D:" << endl;
    Number n4(Number(n1));
    return 0;
}
```

**This outputs:**

```
Part A:
integer argument ctor
Part B:
copy ctor
Part C:
copy ctor
Part D:
```

Notice there is no output for Part D. The output for Parts A and B are what I expected, but the output for the others aren’t.

**I expected this for Parts C and D:**

```
Part C:
copy ctor
move ctor
Part D:
copy ctor
move ctor
```

**Expectation for Part C:**

I expected the `Number{n1}` part of `Number n3{Number{n1}}` to make a temporary nameless `Number` object, because there is no name between `Number` and the opening curly brace, by calling the copy constructor with `n1`. Then I expected `Number n3` to be constructed by calling the move constructor with the temporary object.

**Expectation for Part D:**

Since this is like Part C, except with parentheses instead of curly braces, I expected this part to behave and output in the same way I expected Part C to.

**Question:**

Why does the actual output differ from my expectations and what is the correct way to get my desired output?

**Note:** If you want to compile this in Visual Studio, you need the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) or later for Visual Studio 2012 in order to support the uniform initialization syntax.

Comment: search for "copy elision" and "most vexxing parse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n4` [is a function declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `n3` is caused by [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

Check that [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbd8f0f4b8ed0d97) I've enabled `-fno-elide-constructors` to avoid copy elision. `n3` then shows a sequence of copy and move constructors.

There's a commented out line that tries to use `n4` as an object. If you uncomment it, you'll see the compiler error telling it's a function instead.

For `n4` do not be interpreted as a function declaration you could put extra parentheses around the temporary to prevent it from being viewed as a function parameter: `Number n4((Number(n1)))`. With this and `-fno-elide-constructors` all you've expected happens.

Note that `-fno-elide-constructors` is not present as an option in MSVC.

Comment: You can also prevent the function declaration by writing `Number n4(n1)` or `Number n4(Number(2))`. If you _really_ want the move constructor to be called, write something like `Number n(std::move(Number(2))`. Passing an R-value will also call the move constructor. Trying this out is how I learned about return value optimisation in the first place.

Comment: +1, though, please replace "return value optimization" by "copy elision". RVO ist just one kind of copy elision. But RVO does not apply here because there is no return. ;)